# Connect to a service on a different stack from docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I'm trying to connect a service one in stack abc - abc_one to service two in stack zyx - zyx_two . These services share the network az-network .

I've read [here](https://docs.docker.com/v17.12/docker-cloud/apps/service-links/#discovering-services-or-containers-on-another-stack) that it's possible manually , but I need to do this with docker-compose.yml files for deploying to my swarm .

A simple version of of abc_one is

```
version:  "3.5"

services:

    one:
        image: "10.30.13.81:5000/dotnetmicroservice"
        environment:
            ElasticSearchLogging:Uri: "http://zyx_two:9200/"
        networks:
            - az-network

networks:
    az-network:
        external: true
```

and zyx_two

```
version:  "3.5"

services:

    two:
        image: "10.30.13.81:5000/dotnetmicroservice"
        networks:
            - az-network

networks:
    az-network:
        external: true
```

Comment: Are you having an issue? An error being raised? Or are you just asking if the docker-composes you posted will work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work without adding zyx_ prefix.

**az-network** must be an overlay docker network

```
docker network create -d overlay --attachable az-network
```

**Service name** must be unique on all stacks in the same network.

abc stack  (`docker stack deploy -c abc-compose.yml abc`)

```
version:  "3.5"

services:

    one:
        image: "10.30.13.81:5000/dotnetmicroservice"
        environment:
            ElasticSearchLogging:Uri: "http://two:9200/"
        networks:
            - az-network

networks:
    az-network:
        external: true
```

zyx stack (`docker stack deploy -c zyx-compose.yml zyx`)

```
version:  "3.5"

services:

two:
    image: "10.30.13.81:5000/dotnetmicroservice"
    networks:
        - az-network

networks:
    az-network:
        external: true
```

Comment: Thanks @mounir that works , I believe I was trying that syntax before I added service one to the shared external network and over-complicated things .

Answer (score 0):

From the [docker compose reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#external-1) about the `external` you set to true:

> If set to true specifies that this network has been created outside of Compose. docker-compose up does not attempt to create it and raises an error if it doesn’t exist.

Since both of your `docker-compose` is setting the `external` to true it will raise an error and won't create the network.

Remove the `external` option from one of the docker-composes, do it with the one which will always be run first, so it creates the network and then the other stack just connects to it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion , but that I have already created that external network , that the other services in the network are able to connect to .